# how to create a regular expression that will check if string has n letters, that aren't going upwards in the alphabet

Tags: python, string

Imagine that you get a number `n` and a string with `n` letters.

How would a regex that would check if the letters are NOT going upwards in the alphabet look like?

`n` may range from 1-5.

What I mean by not going upwards:

A valid string for `n=4` may be `abcd`, `bouz`, `zzzz`, `xxxx` etc... and invalid string would be `dcba`, `zzza`, `zoub` etc...

Also how would the regex change if it was exactly the other way around?

I don't even know where to start, because I have only basic knowledge in regex syntax, I've tried to generate some stuff with ai, but it threw out nonsense, like:

`^(?!.*(?:a(?=[bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|b(?=[cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|c(?=[defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|d(?=[efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|e(?=[fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|f(?=[ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|g(?=[hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|h(?=[ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|i(?=[jklmnopqrstuvwxyz])|j(?=[klmnopqrstuvwxyz])|k(?=[lmnopqrstuvwxyz])|l(?=[mnopqrstuvwxyz])|m(?=[nopqrstuvwxyz])|n(?=[opqrstuvwxyz])|o(?=[pqrstuvwxyz])|p(?=[qrstuvwxyz])|q(?=[rstuvwxyz])|r(?=[stuvwxyz])|s(?=[tuvwxyz])|t(?=[uvwxyz])|u(?=[vwxyz])|v(?=[wxyz])|w(?=[xyz])|x(?=[yz])|y(?=z))).{1,5}$`

Comment: Is there a reason this must be done in regex? This can be trivially done with just character comparisons.

Comment: It's a part of a bigger regex, so I would really prefer if it would be done in regex.

Comment: The AI nonsense can be written a bit shorter but basically resembles how such a regex would have to look like.

Comment: What exactly does *"exactly the other way around"* mean?

Comment: "*[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)*"

Comment: @nocomment  "exactly the other way around"  means that the string would be valid if the letters would not be going downwards in the alphabet, so abcd, bouz, zzzz, xxxx would be invalid and dcba, zzza, zoub would be valid

Comment: Why would zoub be valid? It does go down from z to o and from u to b.

Comment: *"What I mean by not going upwards: A valid string for n=4 may be abcd"* - How is abcd not going upwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b(?=\b\w{4}\b)a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*\b`

`\b` at boundaries to check for word

`(?=\b\w{4}\b)` checks for word of length 4 but does not consume

`a*...z*` checks for alphabetical orders i.e. 0 or more a's, then 0 or more b's, etc...

Just reverse `z*...a*` for backwards.